# Is there a general strategy for identifying the automorphism group of a graph?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I understand what an automorphism is, and I can sort of wrap my head around the idea that the set of automorphisms under composition form a group, but when asked to actually *find* the automorphism group of a graph, all I really know how to do is write out all the permutations then figure out which are automorphisms, which is both prohibitively tedious and gives answers as lists of permutations, instead of standard group notation.

Comment: What is "standard group notation" exactly? The permutations *are* the automorphisms, so that's a perfectly good representation of the group.

Comment: I mean, for example, compositions of $S_k$ and $C_k$. While I understand a list of permutations is a correct way of writing an automorphism, $S_{20}$ is much more elegant than writing out more than $2.4 * 10^{18}$ strings.

Comment: When you start getting into real computations, you're not going to get a nice answer like $S_{20}$ except maybe on an exam. Most groups don't have a name.  I think most of the $49,487,365,422$ groups of order $1024$ have no good description but their presentation.

Comment: If I include the restriction that the graph is vertex-transitive, does the problem become simpler?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you doing this by hand for homework, or writing a program for graphs you come across in problems?

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to find the automorphism groups of the graphs of the platonic solids. The tetrahedron was simple, it's $S_4$, but once I get to the cube I'm stuck.

Comment: Oh, well that's a much more reasonable question because that problem has a nice answer. The automorphism group of a cube is the hyperoctahedral group $B_3$ of order $48$. It's a semidirect product of $S_3$ and an elementary abelian $2$-group of order 8.

Comment: For platonic solids you only have to look at subgroups of the orthogonal group, which means your elements will all be rotations and reflections.

Comment: Okay. I can recognize that choosing any two opposite faces and "cycling" through the vertices on those two faces (mapping each corner to the next one, say, clockwise, and doing the same on the opposite face) is an automorphism. There are 3 such pairs of faces and 4 possible states of cycle, so that gives us order of at least $3*4 = 12$. Then I also recognize that switching all pairs of opposite vertices is an automorphism with two possible states, giving us order of at least $12*2 = 24$. What am I missing, since the actual order is 48?

Comment: You can reflect along three axes.

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you mean the axes that run through opposite corners of the graph? Also, I'd prefer to handle this in a "non-geometric" way, if that makes sense -- that is, to just think in terms of mapping vertices to other vertices.

Comment: Each face determines an opposite face. You can permute the pairs of opposite faces arbitrarily. This gives you $6$. Then $8$ reflections $(x,y,z)\mapsto (-x,y,-z)$, etc.) gives you $48$.

Comment: Are the reflections equivalent to swapping opposite faces? If so, I think I follow.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Okay, good. Now, is there an easy way to show that that's the *entire* set of automorphisms? (Sorry for dragging this out so much, but I want to know that I'm well-equipped to handle the other solids correctly.

Comment: I think you can show that the position of the four vertices of one face determines everything else. Maybe try working with that case by case. By the way, just now I entered "symmetry group" into Google and it completed it to "symmetry groups of platonic solids," and the first result there gives you abstract descriptions as well as concrete permutation representations of the groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw in the comments that you are stuck on the automorphism group of the cube graph and want a non-geometric approach.  One way to show that the order of the automorphism group $G$ of the cube graph is $48$ is to use the orbit-stabilizer lemma and to draw the distance partition of the cube graph.

The cube graph is vertex-transitive, and so by the orbit-stabilizer lemma, $|G|= 8 \cdot |G_v|$, where $G_v$ is the set of automorphisms of the graph that fixes vertex $v$.  Without loss of generality, take $v$ to be the identity vertex $000$ (I'm assuming you are familiar with this definition of the cube where the vertices correspond to bit strings of length $3$).  Observe that any permutation of the three coordinates preserves adjacency and fixes $v$.  This proves that $|G_v| \ge 3!=6$.

The distance partition of the cube graph with respect to vertex $v$ can be obtained by doing a breadth-first-search starting at vertex $v$.  The $i$th layer of the distance partition is the set of vertices whose distance to $v$ is exactly $i$.  It can be shown from this drawing of the cube graph that each vertex in the $ith$ layer ($i \ge 2$) has a unique set of neighbors in the previous layer. Hence, any automorphism of the graph which fixes $v$ and each of its neighbors is the trivial automorphism. This proves that $|G_v| \le 3!$.  Hence $|G| = 8 \cdot 3! = 48$.

The above argument gives the order of the automorphism group.  If you also want the structure of this group, it can be shown to be the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}_2^3 \rtimes S_3$.  The geometric approach can be used to show that the group is isomorphic to the direct product $C_2 \times S_4$.

The strategy used here to obtain the automorphism group was to observe that the cube graph can be defined equivalently by adjacencies between bit strings differing in exactly one coordinate and to use the basic theory of group actions. In the geometric approach also, one can consider the action of the automorphism group of the cube on its four diagonals.